# Using home brew to install ethereum but it keeps returning a make error

Tags: go-ethereum, mac-osx, golang

[image]

I am using home brew to install  ethereum but it keeps returning this error. Is there anyway I can fix it?

Comment: Try the non-dev installation.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah Where would I find that ? Forgive me If the question seems stupid. I am in fact a non-dev trying to become one.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions for the non-dev version can be found at [Installation Instructions for Mac](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Mac) and follows:

> ```
> brew tap ethereum/ethereum
> brew install ethereum
> ```

While I'm writing this, I may as well add in the upgrade instructions:

```
brew update
brew upgrade ethereum
```

To find out the installation information:

```
brew info ethereum
```

### Troubleshooting Update

1. What does `brew doctor` report? Does it ask you to execute commands line the following to fix up user permissions?

   ```
   sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/bok/Library/Caches/Homebrew
   ```

   There is a possibility that brew is unable to create the required files in directories with incorrect permissions.
2. From my $HOME directory, when I type the following command, I have an env.sh file:

   ```
   Iota:~ bok$ find . -name 'env.sh'
   ./Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git/build/env.sh
   ```

   and the contents of this file follows:

   ```
   Iota:~ bok$ more ./Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git/build/env.sh
   #!/bin/sh

   set -e

   if [ ! -f "build/env.sh" ]; then
       echo "$0 must be run from the root of the repository."
       exit 2
   fi

   # Create fake Go workspace if it doesn't exist yet.
   workspace="$PWD/build/_workspace"
   root="$PWD"
   ethdir="$workspace/src/github.com/ethereum"
   if [ ! -L "$ethdir/go-ethereum" ]; then
       mkdir -p "$ethdir"
       cd "$ethdir"
       ln -s ../../../../../. go-ethereum
       cd "$root"
   fi

   # Set up the environment to use the workspace.
   # Also add Godeps workspace so we build using canned dependencies.
   GOPATH="$workspace"
   export GOPATH

   # Run the command inside the workspace.
   cd "$ethdir/go-ethereum"
   PWD="$ethdir/go-ethereum"

   # Launch the arguments with the configured environment.
   exec "$@"
   ```

   You could try creating the file above in the same directory on your computer, then run `chmod 755 ./Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git/build/env.sh` to make it an executable file. Then re-run youir `brew install ethereum`.

   You can download this same file from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/build/env.sh.
3. You may want to download the Xcode application from your app store. If you have already done this, make sure your have the 8.0 update - check your app store update list.
4. Looking at the URL provide in your error report https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting:

   - Run `brew update` (**twice**) and `brew doctor` before creating an issue!
5. `brew doctor` earlier told me that I needed to update my command line tools:

   ```
   Iota:Downloads bok$ brew doctor
   ....
   Warning: You have Xcode 8 installed without the CLT;
   this causes certain builds to fail on OS X El Capitan (10.11).
   Please install the CLT via:
     sudo xcode-select --install
   Iota:Downloads bok$ sudo xcode-select --install
   xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
   ```
6. Looking at https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues, you have already reported this issue in [Unable to install go-ethereum #89](https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/89).
7. The issue with `Unexpected header files: /usr/local/include/python2.7/greenlet/greenlet.h` seems to not be a serious problem - see https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/38152 .
8. If you want to use `geth` while your `brew install ethereum` is not working, you can install Ethereum Wallet on your computer from [Ethereum Wallet 0.8.6](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases), and the first time you start Ethereum Wallet, it will download your `geth` binary. You will however not have the Solidity compiler `solc`:

   ```
   Iota:unpacked bok$ pwd
   /Users/bok/Library/Application Support/Ethereum Wallet/binaries/Geth/unpacked
   Iota:unpacked bok$ ll
   total 72784
   drwxr-xr-x  6 bok  staff       204 17 Oct 09:58 .
   drwxr-xr-x  4 bok  staff       136 17 Oct 09:58 ..
   -rw-r--r--  1 bok  staff     32397 16 Oct 20:19 COPYING
   -rw-r--r--  1 bok  staff      7651 16 Oct 20:19 COPYING.LESSER
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 bok  staff  18611260 17 Oct 09:58 geth
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 bok  staff  18611260 16 Oct 20:07 geth-1.4.18-stable-c72f545-darwin-10.6-amd64
   Iota:unpacked bok$ ./geth version
   Geth
   Version: 1.4.18-stable-c72f5459
   ...
   ```

Comment: I tried both of those but it keeps giving me this error. Last 15 lines from /Users/iivri.andre/Library/Logs/Homebrew/ethereum/02.make:
2016-10-17 22:46:10 -0500

make
all

build/env.sh go run build/ci.go install
make: build/env.sh: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: This is the error I got when I ran `brew doctor` /Users/iivri.andre/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-10-18 at 8.36.34 PM.png

Comment: This is the error I got when I ran `brew doctor`
Andres-MacBook-Air:~ iivri.andre$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/python2.7/greenlet/greenlet.h

Comment: I am not getting any response from anyone on github. This is frustrating

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: I accessed a file in the ethereum folder in the Homebrew directory. At the top seems to be the problem. [http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9463/this-is-the-02-make-file-for-the-ethereum-directory-in-homebrew-at-the-top-ther]

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem using by following instructions below. I don't know the reason, but I completely get rid of `brew` to make it run. (mac)

1. install go(I used package)
2. `git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum`
3. `cd go-ethereum && git checkout tags/v1.8.2`
4. run `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 dos2unix`(if you don't have dos2unix, you could brew one, it does not break anything.)
5. `make geth`
6. `ln -s /path/to/origin/geth /path/to/target/geth`

Then run `which geth` you could find your geth. Run `geth version` you can see your version.